# Split big classes into smaller ones

Tags: c#, oop

I've having an issue splitting my main form/class into smaller parts.

The main reason is because of the control events. I can't figure how it would be possible to make the class smaller since it consists of 20 controls (at least) with at least 3 events for each control.

Even some methods I actually managed to move to a separate class they require to send the control as a method argument in order for them to be able to work as they were intended in the first place.

A small example would be

```
public static bool GroupContainsSnippet(TreeView tree, string group, string snippetName)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (tree.Nodes[group] != null)
    {
        result = tree.Nodes[group].Nodes.ContainsKey(snippetName);
    }

    return result;
}
```

For some reason it just feels odd having to send the control in order to do that kind of things, so I'm hoping there is a more clearer way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example, I would create my own TreeView derived class, e.g., MyTreeView, and put in there as much of the TreeView code as makes sense. For example,

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public bool GroupContainsSnippet(string group, string snippetName)
    {
        return Nodes[group] != null && Nodes[group].Nodes.ContainsKey(snippetName);
    }    
}
```

This is a more o-o approach, as it encapsulates your specific TreeView behaviour into its own class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I was looking for a more OOP approach, this seems to be what I should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your class is too big have you looked into partial classes?  Your class isn't going to change in size but it will change the amount of code in one class file you have to work on at any one time.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)